# How do I set css style in states on React?

Tags: css, reactjs, state

I am trying to set an updated size to an element using this statement.

```
const [size, setSize] = useState({});
```

I want to state my initial size to:

```
transform: scale(1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Once the element is clicked, I want to enlarge my element to this:

```
transform: scale(2, 2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

This is how I will be triggering the element to update to the new setSize.

```
const onClickHandler = (event) => {
setSize= transform: scale(2, 2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

**Option 1**

```
const [style, setStyle] = useState({});

const onClickHandler = () => setStyle({
  transform: "scale(2, 2) translate3d(0, 0, 0)"
});

return (
  <div style={style}>
    {/* some components */}
  </div>
);
```

**Option 2**

```
const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);
const style = useMemo(() => ({ // to prevent unnecessary re-rendering
  transform: `scale(${scale}, ${scale}) translate3d(0, 0, 0)`
}), [scale]);
const onClickHandler = () => setScale(2);


return (
  <div style={style}>
    {/* some components */}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Option 2 works extremely well and I will continue to use this format moving forward. :) I'm trying to find a way to stack css lines in "style" to center the element when scaled. Do you think this is the right way to add css lines? 
<br/><br/>
const style = useMemo(() => ({ // to prevent unnecessary re-rendering
  transform: `scale(${scale}, ${scale}) translate3d(0, 0, 0)`, transformOrigin: `center`
}), [scale]);
const onClickHandler = () => setScale(2);

Comment: If `transformOrigin: center` is the CSS you would like to add, then yeah of course.